# Passing an additional input to Keras Deep Network to calculate a custom cost function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

We have Input Images (input_x) of 1000x512x512x1, weight maps(input_w) of 1000x512x512x1. In fact, each image has its own weight map that has been produced before the network run, thus we have to pass those as the second input.  Both are fed to the network, although these weight maps are just for being multiplied to Loss function and are not real tensors( they don't come from any layers and remain input of the model till reach loss function). First, there is two input for our model and only one output:

```
 model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_x, input_w], outputs=final_output)
```

and the input shapes are changed at the beginning of the network:

```
input_x = layers.Input(shape=(512,512,1))
input_w = layers.Input(shape=(512,512,1))
```

the input_x go through layers of network, but the input_w is used only in the customLoss :

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=customLoss(input_w), metrics=[dice_coef, mean_iou])
```

which is a wrapper due to the additional parameter of input_w:

```
def customLoss(input_w): 
  def loss_fcn(y_true, y_pred):
     bce = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
     dice_term = K.exp(1 + dice_coef(y_true, y_pred, 1.0))
     return input_w * (bce - dice_term)
  return loss_fcn
```

and after producing X and W from the dataset, we called fit with 2 inputs, the X is input_x (images) and W is (weight maps).

```
history= my_model.fit([X,W],y,validation_split=0.1, epochs=5000,batch_size=8, callbacks=[best_check])
```

Everything seems correct for me but I receive the error of

```
Epoch 1/5000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b756059772c5> in <module>()
      6                               patience=6,
      7                               verbose=1, mode='auto')
----> 8 history= my_model.fit([X,W],y,validation_split=0.1, epochs=5000,batch_size=8, callbacks=[best_check])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1037                                         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1038                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1039                                         validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1040 
   1041     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
    197                     ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    198 
--> 199                 outs = f(ins_batch)
    200                 outs = to_list(outs)
    201                 for l, o in zip(out_labels, outs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [8,512,512,1] vs. [8,512,512]
     [[{{node loss_1/mask_output_loss/mul_2}} = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_1/Adam/gradients/loss_1/mask_output_loss/mul_2_grad/Reshape_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](_arg_input_4_0_1/_3633, loss_1/mask_output_loss/sub_2)]]
     [[{{node metrics_1/mean_iou/mean_iou_2/confusion_matrix/assert_non_negative_1/assert_less_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch/_4057}} = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6795_...ert/Switch", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

without passing weight maps, everything works well but now it has this error.

Comment: Hi @patric! Can you add a `model.summary()` output to the question? Also, is the indentation in `custom_loss` correct (especially, first `return`) or not? Can you provide more detaild stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @MikhailStepanov! the model is too long (this is like LinkNet structure).
Both indentations are correct in the code, I will edit it here. what kind of detail shall I provide?

Comment: Where (at which line of code/inside which function) execution is broken? At least, is it occurred inside your `costomLoss`?

Comment: It is broke first in fit function! no the customLoss is not involved!
the last 2 lines are :

--> 528   c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530 # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [8,512,512,1] vs. [8,512,512]

Comment: Somewhere between tf api and keras fit function execution just falied; there are incompatible layers or incorrect operation. I guess, add some ~20 last lines of a stacktrace as a code block to your question will help. For now, it  still unclear what's the main reason, but it's in a tensor/layer/operation which connected somehow to the weights input

Comment: @MikhailStepanov I'm sure the network layers are connected correctly and loss function operation has been tested on several datasets well.  Actually, before adding W  as the second input and using it in the loss function, everything works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these codes were written truly, However, since this project was developing in google Colab some weird faults happened so that after several re-connecting the page the problem solved!
the error was due to the disconnection probably!